# google analytics embed API comperission

Tags: charts, analytics

so i stuck in another problem,
i'm using google embed API to creating a dashboard in my admin, so what i want is that if a user select two different websites from two different drop downs and click on submit button on next page he got only data of his selected websites in view container and in charts also
if any one can help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.